# Node rotation out of angle

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I created a circle by:

```
class FourColorCircle : SKShapeNode {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.createCircle()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func createCircle () {
        let center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        // node1
        let node1bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        node1bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0.78, endAngle: 2.35, clockwise: true)
        node1bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

        let node1 = SKShapeNode(path: node1bezierPath.CGPath)
        node1.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
        node1.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
        node1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: node1bezierPath.CGPath)
        node1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        node1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        node1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactBodies.redNode.rawValue
        node1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup.redBall.rawValue | ballGroup.blueBall.rawValue | ballGroup.greenBall.rawValue | ballGroup.yellowBall.rawValue
        self.addChild(node1)
        // node2
        let node2bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        node2bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 2.35, endAngle: 3.92, clockwise: true)
        node2bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

        let node2 = SKShapeNode(path: node2bezierPath.CGPath)
        node2.strokeColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        node2.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        node2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: node2bezierPath.CGPath)
        node2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        node2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        node2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactBodies.blueNode.rawValue
        node2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup.redBall.rawValue | ballGroup.blueBall.rawValue | ballGroup.greenBall.rawValue | ballGroup.yellowBall.rawValue
        self.addChild(node2)
        // node3
        let node3bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        node3bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 3.92, endAngle: 5.48, clockwise: true)
        node3bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

        let node3 = SKShapeNode(path: node3bezierPath.CGPath)
        node3.strokeColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        node3.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        node3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: node3bezierPath.CGPath)
        node3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        node3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        node3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactBodies.greenNode.rawValue
        node3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup.redBall.rawValue | ballGroup.blueBall.rawValue | ballGroup.greenBall.rawValue | ballGroup.yellowBall.rawValue
        self.addChild(node3)
        // node4
        let node4bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        node4bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: 5.48, endAngle: 0.78, clockwise: true)
        node4bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)

        let node4 = SKShapeNode(path: node4bezierPath.CGPath)
        node4.strokeColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
        node4.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
        node4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: node4bezierPath.CGPath)
        node4.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        node4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        node4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = contactBodies.yellowNode.rawValue
        node4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup.redBall.rawValue | ballGroup.blueBall.rawValue | ballGroup.greenBall.rawValue | ballGroup.yellowBall.rawValue
        self.addChild(node4)

    }

    func rotate(angle : CGFloat, animated : Bool) {
        var rotateAction : SKAction!

        if animated {
            rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 0.2)
        }
        else {
            rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 0)
        }

        self.runAction(rotateAction)
    }
}
```

I set it to rotate by 90 degree every time when the user taps the screen:

centerCircle.rotate(-3.14/2, animated: true)

I also declared a small ball, which will fall from top of screen and contact the center circle. The game logic is to match the color between the small ball and the sector of the circle, if the color doesn't match, game over.
The issue I have right now is that, **no matter what**, the circle should be like this:

[image]

But when if I just keep tap on the screen to rotate the circle and the game keeps restart, the circle will rotate out of angle, like this:

[image]

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: When the game restarts couldn't you just set the `zRotation` of the ball back to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I think you should use `CGFloat(M_PI)` instead of `3,14` because `3,14` is a bad approximation of the pi.

Secondly, is it possible that when you tap faster than 0.2 seconds the `SKAction` you run is run over uncompleted rotation causing a shift? I'm also newbie with the `SKAction`, so I'm not sure how it would behave but could you try to tap more slowly (after fixing the `M_PI`) and see how it behaves? If the problem is caused by running a second rotation over uncompleted rotation you can disable the second tap until the rotation is complete or you can queue it to execute after the first rotation is completed.

Comment: It seems like the 3.14 is causing the problem. I changed it to `CGFloat(M_PI)`, and the problem is gone. Thanks.